# Trazer a palavra HISTORICO quando a Data da linha for menor que as datas anteriores,

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma consulta onde devo registrar as linhas com erro com a palavra Histórico, as linhas que trazem a data MENOR que qualquer uma das datas das linhas anteriores devem apresentar a palavra HISTORICO, (No mesmo Item)

Podem dar uma ajuda? a coluna em questão é a TIPO,

o resultado deve ser como a tabela abaixo.

Tb_importacao [cod_titulo,data,imp_situacao]

```
CD    Item    ValA    ValB    Data                       Tipo
01    A       10      15      2017-05-01 00:01:57.000    0
02    A       10      15      2017-05-01 00:02:15.000    0
03    A       10      15      2017-05-01 00:02:20.000    0
04    A       10      15      2017-05-01 00:03:40.000    0
05    A       10      15      2017-05-01 00:03:35.000    HISTORICO!
06    A       10      15      2017-05-01 00:04:20.000    0
07    A       10      15      2017-05-01 00:04:25.000    0
08    A       10      15      2017-05-01 00:04:50.000    0
09    A       10      15      2017-05-01 00:04:10.000    HISTORICO!
10    A       10      15      2017-05-01 00:04:30.000    0    <-- ??
11    B       10      15      2017-05-01 00:05:10.000    0
12    B       10      15      2017-05-01 00:05:30.000    0
13    B       10      15      2017-05-01 00:05:05.000    HISTORICO!
14    B       10      15      2017-05-01 00:05:50.000    0
```

Comment: Qual banco de dados está utilizando? Poderia postar o código da query que já conseguiu elaborar? Poderia postar a estrutura das tabelas que precisa consultar (se possível compartilhar no sqlfidle)?

Comment: Olá Amigo , confesso que este é meu primeiro post e ainda estou aprendendo, o BD é SQLServer, 
as informações vem todas de uma única tabela, 

eu montei o exemplo acima por receio de postar dados da empresa que trabalho, porém se não der pra dar uma idéia com eles, eu posso tentar montar algo diferente, 
Estou estudando os posts ainda para aprender a usar sqlfidle,

Comment: Só por essa informação que você postou fica complicado ajudar.

Tente colocar mais informações sobre o problema, ou alguma query que você já fez. Eu não entendi muito bem

Comment: @AlexandreGonçalves: Qual a versão do SQL Server? // Para avaliar a sequência na coluna [Data] é necessário que cada linha tenha uma identificação única, que permita obter a ordem esperada. Como se pode identificar a ordem das linhas? No exemplo que postou há linhas repetidas para as colunas CD/Item/ValA/ValB.

Comment: @JoséDiz , Obrigado pela atenção, na correria acabei postando errado, 
sql server 2014, 

A coluna CD é unica, não se repete, 

Isso já da pra ter uma ideia? 

Tkss

Comment: @JoséDiz, A coluna onde traz histórico, seria um Case When, ou um select aninhado?
Eu ainda tenho dificuldades, estou aprendendo,

Comment: @AlexandreGonçalves: Supondo a sequência de horários 4:50, 4:10, 4:30, 5:10, quais valores devem ser marcados como HISTORICO: somente 4:10 ou 4:10 e 4:30?

Comment: @JoséDiz Muito obrigado pela atenção, passei o dia todo treinando seus exemplos, o exemplo código #1 funcionou perfeitamente ficando desta forma: 
SELECT top 100  
 [GRU_CD]
    ,[GRU_PF] as 'Grua'   
    ,[GRU_DT_REGISTRO] as 'Registro'
    ,[GRU_DS_DATUM] 
 ,case when [GRU_DT_REGISTRO] < lag([GRU_DT_REGISTRO]) over ( Order By [GRU_CD] ,[GRU_PF])
   then 'HISTORICO' else '0' end as Tipo
  FROM [KLABIN_SGL].[dbo].[TB_GRUA]
  Where [GRU_PF] in ('TE0048')
  AND DATEPART(mm,[GRU_DT_REGISTRO]) = 5
  Order By [GRU_CD] ,[GRU_PF]

Comment: @JoséDiz porém eu preciso de algo que funcione como no código #2, 
Ele deve verificar TODOS os itens anteriores, e se a linha atual for menor, então deverá trazer a palavra Historico, 
Supondo a sequência de horários 4:50, 4:10, 4:30, 5:10 neste caso deverá marcar como Historico os item 4:10 & 4:30 levando em consideração o Item e CD, 
Tentei adaptar seu código #2 mas não rodou, marcou "" em todas,  vou postar o cod que gerei na minha tentativa:

Comment: @JoséDiz Segue, 

SELECT TOP 100 [GRU_CD]
      ,[GRU_PF]
      ,[GRU_DT_REGISTRO]   

   , case when exists (   
   Select * From [KLABIN_SGL].[dbo].[TB_GRUA] as T2 
    Where T2.GRU_CD < T1.GRU_CD And        
    T2.[GRU_DT_REGISTRO] > T1.[GRU_DT_REGISTRO])
   Then  'Hist' else '' end as Tipo   
  FROM [KLABIN_SGL].[dbo].[TB_GRUA] as T1
  Where [GRU_PF] in ('TE0048')
  AND DATEPART(mm,[GRU_DT_REGISTRO]) = 5
  Order By [GRU_CD] ,[GRU_PF]


Este é o que deveria analisar todos os itens anteriores e verificar se minha linda é menor, então marcar HIST, 
Isso tem solução?

Comment: @JoséDiz por exemplo nessa linha, 
Ele deveria marcar HIST 2 x, seguindo seu exemplo 2 nas linhas

1532579 TE0048 2017-05-01 01:35:51.000  0
1532600 TE0048 2017-05-01 01:36:51.000  0
1532618 TE0048 2017-05-01 01:31:51.000  HISTORICO -- Aqui
1532654 TE0048 2017-05-01 01:35:05.000  0 Aqui
1532699 TE0048 2017-05-01 01:39:51.000  0
1532703 TE0048 2017-05-01 01:40:51.000  0

Answer (score 0):

Eis uma abordagem que analisa todas as linhas anteriores:

```
-- código #2
SELECT CD, Item, ValA, ValB, [Data],
       case when exists (SELECT * from Tabela as T2
                           where T2.CD < T1.CD 
                                 and T2.[Data] > T1.[Data])
            then 'HISTORICO!' else '0' end as Tipo
  from Tabela as T1;
```

Mas se for necessário analisar somente a linha imediatamente anterior, a função [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh231256.aspx) pode ser utilizada, talvez gerando execução mais eficiente.

```
-- código #1
SELECT CD, Item, ValA, ValB, Data,
       case when [Data] < lag([Data]) over (order by CD asc)
            then 'HISTORICO!' else '0' end as Tipo
  from Tabela;
```

---

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**
Considerando-se comentários postados no tópico, me parece que a consulta não é por GRU_CD mas sim por GRU_PF + GRU_CD.

Eis atualização do código #2, considerando-se os nomes de colunas e tabela:

```
-- código #3 v2
SELECT GRU_PF as Grua, GRU_CD, 
       convert(char(10), GRU_DT_REGISTRO, 103) as Dia,
       convert(char(8), GRU_DT_REGISTRO, 108) as Hora,
       case when exists (SELECT *
                           from KLABIN_SGL.dbo.TB_GRUA as T2 
                           where T2.GRU_PF = T1.GRU_PF
                                 and T2.GRU_CD < T1.GRU_CD 
                                 and T2.GRU_DT_REGISTRO > T1.GRU_DT_REGISTRO)
            then 'Hist' else '' end as Tipo 
  from KLABIN_SGL.dbo.TB_GRUA as T1
  where GRU_PF in ('TE0048')
        and convert(char(6), T1.GRU_DT_REGISTRO, 112) = '201705'
  order by GRU_PF, GRU_CD;
```

Atento que o domínio dos dois SELECT deve ser o mesmo. Desta forma, qualquer alteração na cláusula WHERE externa deve ser refletida na cláusula WHERE do SELECT que está na função EXISTS.

Comment: @AlexandreGonçalves: Considerando-se a informação "deve verificar TODOS os itens anteriores", então a solução é o código #2, ok? // Considerando-se comentários que postou no tópico, me parece que a consulta não é por GRU_CD mas sim por GRU_PF + GRU_CD. Vide código #3 acima.